# calling a another function when window size is resized

Tags: angularjs

I have to display Image albums . Till `@media` element `width 700px` I can display 3 images per slide , below `@media width :700px` i need to display 1 image per slide.

For displaying 3 image per slide , I written a function `showfilteredImages();`

```
$scope.imagemaindiv
```

will have all images from backend

```
$scope.imagemaindiv = [{
    'img': "image1.png",
    "id": 1
}, {
    'img': "image2.png",
    "id": 2
}, {
    'img': "image3.png",
    "id": 3
}, {
    'img': "image4.png",
    "id": 4
}, {
    'img': "image5.png",
    "id": 5
}, {
    'img': "image6.png",
    "id": 6
}]
$scope._firstImgIndex = 0;
$scope._lastImgIndex = 2;
$scope.showFilteredImages = function() {
    $scope.filteredImages = [];
    for (var i = $scope._firstImgIndex; i <= $scope._lastImgIndex; i++) {
        $scope.filteredImages.push($scope.imagemaindiv[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use bootstrap do do this thing plus do you need to do it bu JS only

Answer (score 1):

Following code might work for you.:).Try for this.

```
var data=angular.element($window);
data.bind('resize',function(){

//call your another function here:

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function ($window) {

     return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>window size: {{width}}px</div>'
     };

     function link(scope, element, attrs){

       scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

       angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
       alert();
         scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

         // manuall $digest required as resize event
         // is outside of angular
         scope.$digest();
       });

     }

 }]);
```

Comment: this will show alert when you will resize the window